# Maximum value of function $f(x,y) = xy^2$ with constraint $x^2 + y^2 = 8$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Can you help me to find the maximum value of $f(x,y) = xy^2$ with the constraint that the x and y coordinates must satisfy $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 = 8$

How do I start with this?

Comment: Do you know the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)? This is a classic problem involving them.

Comment: Problem 2 on the link might help: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I'll check and post further questions. I was never taught this so was trying to get a direction.

Comment: There are plenty of examples in [this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagrange-multiplier)

Comment: More simply than Lagrange: $y^2 = 8 - x^2$ hence you need to find the max of $F(x) = x(8-x^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lagrange multipliers

$$\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$$
$$(y^2,2xy)=\lambda(2x,2y)$$

$2xy=\lambda2y$ gives $x=\lambda$ then from $x^2+y^2=8$ 
together withe $y^2=\lambda2x$ one have
$$x^2-8+2\lambda x=x^2-8+2 x^2=3x^2-8=0$$ so 
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}$$ and 
$$y^2=8-x^2=8-\frac{8}{3}=\frac{16}{3}$$
so $$y=\pm\frac{4}{\sqrt3}$$
To find the maximum you have to evaluate the function at these 4 values and compare. Immediately you have that $x>0$ and the function reaches maximum at 
$$(x,y)=\left(\sqrt{\frac{8}3},\pm\frac{4}{\sqrt3}\right)$$

Comment: Hi, Just to clarify, we substitute the four possible points in function f and check if the value is >0. If so it is a maximum, right? Also, I am required to explain these results, any idea of what should I say? How to interpret this? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you compare between all values to determine the maximum and minimum. Regarding adding the words, you have the Lagrange multipliers and the condition. Using the condition you express one variable using the other one and obtain quadratic equation which you solve then substitute the result to get the other variable. then compare. Look at the following examples you don't need more words then they have.http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx

Answer (score -1):

**HINT:** Use Lagrangian multipliers. $$f(x,y)= \lambda  \nabla g(x,y)$$

Comment: Thanks. I'll check and post further questions. I was never taught this so was trying to get a direction.

Comment: Check your formula before hinting.